# importing dictionary from python file to another

Tags: python, file, dictionary, import, python-import

So i was working on my project where i needed to import dictionaries from one python file to another both files are in same directory. And the purpose of importing dictionary is just for reading purposes. So first time i imported the dictionary everything worked fine but subsequently whenever i tried on some cases i got only an empty dictionary but there was no error i tried printing the dictionary in both the files and in file1 the dictionary has some content but in file2 after import it only shows empty dictionary.

File1:-

```
dic1 = {}
dic['abcd'] = 4
print(dic1)#output{'abcd': 4}
```

File2:-

```
from File1 import dic1
print(dic1)#output {}
```

Comment: please edit your question with the code you have tried

Comment: Works for me. Prints `{'abcd': 4} {'abcd': 4}` while running File2!

Comment: The problem is that you're using `dic['abcd'] = 4` instead of `dic1['abcd'] = 4`, and then you're importing the empty `dic1`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your File1:

```
dic['abcd'] = 4
```

- That looks pretty suspicious from the start, because you haven't made
  the dictionary `dic` anywhere, you have made dictionary `dic1`.
- In File2, you are import `dic1` (the empty dict), not `dic`.

## Solution

Change File1 to this:

```
dic1 = {}
dic1['abcd'] = 4
print(dic1)
```

This should help.

*Also, if you're actually using variable names like `File1` and `dict1` in your project, I highly recommend choosing more descriptive
names.*